# Is there a .Net (prefer F# or C#) implementation of the Hilbert-Huang Transform?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, statistics, scientific-computing

Hilbert-Huang Transform, Empirical Mode Decomposition...

I have found it implemented in R and Matlab. I'd like to find an open source implementation of it in C#/F#/.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of quality open source numerical code for .NET is tiny. I struggled to find a decent FFT only a couple of years ago. So I seriously doubt you'll find a decent existing implementation of this algorithm because it is pretty obscure!

Your best bet is to build a Hilbert-Huang Transform in terms of an FFT (like the one from either of my F# books or the F#.NET Journal articles) which is, I guess, what you did in MATLAB and R?

I'm curious why you would want this though? It doesn't look very compelling to me...

Comment: I didn't do it in MATLAB or R--I just found something that someone else had done. And it's quite different FFT (similar in purpose, yes, very different in approach), which is one of the reasons it's interesting to me. For the things I'm working with, FFT has various significant issues.

Comment: @taotree: I meant that I suspect the R and MATLAB code you found uses the FFT to compute the Hilbert transform. You might appreciate some of the alternative techniques I described in the third chapter of my PhD thesis: http://www.ffconsultancy.com/free/thesis.pdf

Comment: I appreciate your response. It's not a Hilbert transform, and as far as I know an FFT would not be used in it's calculation.

I skimmed through your thesis, it looks interesting. It appears you suggest standard wavelet analysis but propose a new mother wavelet?

Comment: @taotree: Standard complex-valued continuous wavelet transform with a new mother wavelet and new quantifications of instantaneous frequency and amplitude from the results.

Comment: @JonHarrop The R implementation of HHT that I have seen definitely do not use FFT. The Hilbert transform is done once the IMFs have been created. Huang used splines to decompose the signal.

Comment: @IanThompson: That's very interesting, thanks. Do you know what the motivation is for not using an FFT?

Comment: @JonHarrop Not sure if I can do the answer justice in a comment, but here goes: Huang was interested in processing data measuring turbulence. A data signal representing turbulence is not one with smooth linear transitions, and most decomposition methods including FFT do not deal well with non-linear transitions. To FFT, these transitions appear as noise. However, with turbulence data, it was the sudden transitions in the signal that Huang was interested in, so he set out to develop another method of decomposition that was closer to continuous than discreet ... continued.

Comment: @JonHarrop ... so as to capture those non-linear transitions in the signal. The decomposition first decomposes the signal into IMFs (see the wikipedia article for a full explanation), after which the Hilbert transform is applied to those IMFs. Huang's method was to form a cubic spline through the local maxima and minima of the signal, take the mean of splines and subtract the original signal. This worked well for Huang's application on turbulence data, but presents challenges for continuous signal processing due to problems with cubic splines. If I get time I will do a Q&A on this later.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my implementation of the Hilbert transform from Matlab.  I've done some comparisons with Matlab's output and this code seems to produce identical answers, but I have **not done any kind of extensive testing.**

This uses the publicly-available MathNet library to do the FFT/iFFT calculations.

```
public static Complex[] MatlabHilbert(double[] xr)
    {
        var fft = new MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.Algorithms.DiscreteFourierTransform();
        var x = (from sample in xr select new Complex(sample, 0)).ToArray();
        fft.BluesteinForward(x, FourierOptions.Default);
        var h = new double[x.Length];
        var fftLengthIsOdd = (x.Length | 1) == 1;
        if (fftLengthIsOdd)
        {
            h[0] = 1;
            for (var i = 1; i < xr.Length / 2; i++) h[i] = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            h[0] = 1;
            h[(xr.Length / 2)] = 1;
            for (var i = 1; i < xr.Length / 2; i++) h[i] = 2;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) x[i] *= h[i];
        fft.BluesteinInverse(x, FourierOptions.Default);
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Dave, is this an implementation of the Hilbert-Huang transform (HHT)?

Comment: @tofutim No, it's not. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Huang_transform